# Don't you read blithely as /blaɪθlɪ/ in UK?

Tags: pronunciation

> “They order the toasted cheese sandwiches **blithely**, “ ([audio](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/478))
>   (by Edward Field, from [writersalmanac](http://writersalmanac.publicradio.org/index.php?date=2014/10/30).publicradio.org)

The reader, Mr. Garrison Keillor, sounds to be pronouncing ‘*blithely*’ as /blaɪθlɪ/. Is the word pronounced only as / blaɪðlɪ/ in UK? His pronunciation is not found in both [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/blithe) and [other](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blithe) oxford dictionary online.

Comment: Huh, can't speak for the UK, but that's how I've always pronounced it down here in Australia.

Comment: The word is always pronounced with a voiced /ð/ sound in British English. Kellor's pronunciation sounds very odd to me.

Comment: He's not sounding oddly, it's on US dictionaries: [M-W](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/blithe), [RHD](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blithe?s=t).

Comment: Keillor is American (Minnesota). He is pronouncing -th- as an unvoiced dental but in this word, it is normally voiced in American English. But one does not hear it much (outside academe), so it could be a word he had never heard but had only read.

Comment: I have *never* heard the word pronounced the way M-W gives it. The [aI] vowel is always longer, and the dental is always voiced.

Comment: I'n British and that's not how I pronounce it. I don't do IPA so can't provide how I say it in text but it's much closer to this http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blithely. For me his TH is over pronounced and he seems to stick an A into the LY that isn't there for me.

Comment: @ruakh Heh, yes, reading it back now, that's a less-than-helpful comment on a question regarding different pronunciations. /blaɪðli/ is how I have always pronounced it.

Comment: @TRomano Keillor is a very well read and educated man, but he has a distinct style of diction and intonation.  As for the US, I am far more used to hearing the TH spoken the way that the OALD gives.

Comment: @Jason Patterson: You seem to be saying something not incompatible with what I was saying, that the voiced dental with long [aI] vowel (per the OALD) is by far the more common; I said the OALD pronunciation was the *only* one I'd ever heard. We differ only in this respect: what you've heard only infrequently I've never heard. I have never heard the word said the way Keillor says it in that recording.  If you've heard it both ways, is there a regional element?

Comment: @TRomano Sorry, I was mostly trying to identify Garrison Keillor and let you know that it was not a lack of education but instead likely a peculiar style of speaking.  I've heard the word pronounced both ways, but most use the OALD version.  I haven't noticed a particular regional distinction.

Comment: OK, but I did not imply that Keillor lacked education. I said that perhaps he had read the word, but had not really heard  it said much. Minnesotans, after all, are not a blithe folk. Hard to be blithe when it's minus 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know a few women named Blythe (in the US), and they all go by a pronunciation with the voiceless fricative.  I can't say I've heard the word "blithely" spoken all that often, but I would assume the root could have the same pronunciation as the name.  I think both pronunciations are possible.

Comment: The girl's name *Blythe* is pronounced (here in the US) differently than the adjective|adverb *blithe|blithely*, in my experience.